# Webpack dev server - error with Hot Module Replacement

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use Webpack dev server for development and would like to use [hot module replacement](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-module-replacement) feature, but when I run dev server I get error:

```
ERROR in debug (bower component)
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./dist/debug.js in /Users/and/devel/WebstormProjects/Wonderland_front/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/sockjs-client/node_modules/debug
 @ debug (bower component) 1:17-43
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Wond",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Internal evidence application",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --hot --inline --progress --colors --port 8090"
  },
  "author": "And",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "backbone": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.9.3",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "cookies-js": "^1.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.15.35",
    "events": "^1.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "immutablediff": "0.4.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-resizable-columns": "^0.2.3",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "json-markup": "^0.1.6",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^5.0.13",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-mixin": "^3.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "select2": "^4.0.0",
    "select2-bootstrap-css": "^1.4.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "0.0.2",
    "typeahead.js": "^0.11.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.5.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
console.log("target is event is " + TARGET);

var common = {
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    entry: './src/script/index.jsx',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|other_modules)/
            },
            {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass']},
            {test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less']},
            { test: /\.woff$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[path][name].[ext]" },
            { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=[path][name].[ext]" },
            {test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/, loader: "file-loader"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BowerWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 3 versions']})];
    }
};

if(TARGET === 'dev' || !TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(common,{
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,

            // display only errors to reduce the amount of output
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'index.js',
            publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
        }
    });
}
```

If I remove `--hot` and `--inline` flags, dev server works (without hot module replacement feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for this problem. I just started getting this error when I added a devServer block in the config with `inline: true`.

```
config.devServer = {
  contentBase: config.output.path,  // We want to re-use this path
  noInfo: false,
  debug: false, // Makes no difference
  port: 5566,
  https: true,
  colors: true,
  //hot: true,    // Pass this from the command line as '--hot', which sets up the HotModuleReplacementPlugin automatically
  inline: true   // Setting this to false clears the error
};
```

Setting `inline: false` removes the console error.

---- Edit ----
I believe this problem is related to https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2109. Socket-IO is used by the hot-reloader when inline is used, hence the problem only shows up when you use hot + inline.

As a workaround, I'm adding these two scripts to my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm run fixDistDebugRef",
  "fixDistDebugRef": "mkdir -p node_modules/debug/dist && cp node_modules/debug/debug.js node_modules/debug/dist/"
}
```

...which adds the missing file that the error refers to, after `npm install` is run.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by dumping bower-webpack-plugin from my config.  This was suggested by one of the posters on the https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2109 thread that was referenced by @u_glow.

Without that plugin present, Webpack won't look for modules in the bower_components folder unless you specifically tell it to.  I did that by adding the following to my webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components']
},
```

(Memo to self: don't blindly install plug-ins until you're absolutely sure that you need them.)